# PHP Count From Foreach Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, count

I'm trying to use php and count the number of images from a foreach loop, but my code is not returning the number from the loop. I've tried many ways, but heres the current way im trying..

Heres my code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$post = get_post( $id );

if ( $post ): 

    $images = get_field('gallery', $id);

    if ( $images ):

    // initiate count var
    $count = 0;

       foreach( $images as $image ):

            // count
            $count++;

            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">';

                echo '<div class="product-item">';

                    echo '<a href="' . $image['url'] .'" data-fancybox="product-gallery" class="product-page-gallery-image">';
                        echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '"/>';
                        echo '<p>' . $image['title'] . '</p>';
                    echo '</a>';

                echo '</div>';


            echo '</div>';

       endforeach;

            // echo count
            echo $count;

    endif;

endif;
```

Comment: If you want to iterate over the $images variable it has to be an array. If it is an array, you can count with count($images); and you don't have to increment the $count variable. On my machine the counter you implemented is working.

Comment: What you have should work but, as Thomas said in his comment, there are easier ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: using ' echo count($images); ' doesnt return a value for me either

Comment: I can't imagine why not. Maybe it is hiding insight some other tags insight the view? Please try a var_dump($count) or var_dump(count($images)) to show it a way more aggressive.

Comment: Do you get any images outputted? Because if `if ( $images )` is false then the count is not counted and not echoed. Same thing with `if ( $post ):`, start from the top and var_dump your variables

Comment: what does `var_dump($images)` give you? Seems you have an empty array or null variable

Comment: found my issue, that code there is wrapped in a php function, which is the action thats being called via ajax onclick for some tabs i have. So when i click the tab then it outputs the count... Stupid me, thanks alot for the help guys!